# Magent 2 : We can't initialize Express Checkout. error on paypal express checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, magento2.3.1, paypal-express

I have checked on stackexchange but not found correct answer

I am using Magento version 2.3.1

In my site have multi website with klarna checkout

when i am choose paypal express checkout payment method in checkout

so its giving me error and redirect to cart page with cart empty

Error show in cart page : **We can't initialize Express Checkout.**

not order placed in backend as well.

anyone help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Garchar please share screen

Comment: @Pradip i am also facing similar issue how did you fixed it ?